# switch case on class type java

Tags: java, types, switch-statement

I want to create a function that returns a value of the type passed as an argument.
for that I wanted to use a switch on the type of the argument, but I didn't have to do the right thing.
what is the correct way:

```
public <T> T threadLocalRandom(Class<T> type){
    switch (type){
        case Integer i:
            return (T) ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt();
        case Double:
            return ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble();
        case Boolean:
            return ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextBoolean();
    }
}

public <T> T threadLocalRandom(Class<T> type){
    switch (type.getClass().getSimpleName()){
        case "Integer":
            return (T) ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt();
        case "Double":
            return ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble();
        case "Boolean":
            return ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextBoolean();
    }
}
```

in any case I have an error because I return an Interger, a Double or a Boolean while the method wants to return a type T
Thanks
How to make the Type T match the type returned by the switch?

Comment: This does not (yet) exist in the current version of Java (Java 18). But it's a feature that might be added in a future version. In fact, it's a [preview feature](https://openjdk.org/jeps/406) in Java 17 and 18.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a dynamic [`cast()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#cast-java.lang.Object-) operation you can apply to the result:

```java
return type.cast(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt());
```

I'd be curious to know how you use your method. It seems likely there would be a cleaner way to embody and access this functionality.

Comment: perfect, thanks.
Do you know if I can switch on type directly rather than type.getClass().getSimpleName()?

Comment: @FouvetSébastien Not yet. This is the subject of [JEP 406.](https://openjdk.org/jeps/406)